# How do I reduce a list in a Magnolia JavaScript model?

Tags: javascript, freemarker, ecmascript-5, nashorn, magnolia

I'm attempting to reduce a FreeMarker list in a [Magnolia JavaScript model](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/How+to+work+with+JavaScript+models). I want all items that start with a capital "P".

```
[#assign list = ["Poker", "Pet", "Dog", "Cat", "Penguin", "Paddle", "punk"]]
```

My function should return:

```
["Poker", "Pet", "Penguin", "Paddle"]
```

### Attempts

I attempted to use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var Model = function() {
  this.reduceList = function(list) {
    return list.reduce(function(reducedList, item) {
      if (item.indexOf('P') !== -1) {
        reducedList.push(item);
      }
      return reducedList;
    }, []);
  }
};

new Model();
```

```
[#assign filteredList = model.reduceList(['Poker', 'Pet', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Penguin', 'Paddle', 'punk'])]
```

However, I get the following error.

```
jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: list.reduce is not a function
```

**Note:** Magnolia JavaScript models are built on [Nashorn](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/nashorn/).

### Debugging

When I return the type of the list:

```js
this.reduceList = function(list) {
  return typeof list;
}
```

I get an object:

```
object
```

When I return the list as a string:

```js
this.reduceList = function(list) {
  return list.toString();
};
```

I get a list:

```
[Poker, Pet, Dog, Cat, Penguin, Paddle, punk]
```

How do I reduce a list in a Magnolia JavaScript model?

Comment: Does my answer helps you?

Comment: @prasanakannan No. Filter throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `filter()` method. Here is a code sample:

```js
var Model = function() {
  this.reduceList = function(list) {
    return Java.from(list).filter(function(item) {
      return item[0] === 'P'
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Filter throws the same error: `jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: list.filter is not a function`.

Comment: Also, arrow functions were introduced in ES6. Nashorn uses ES5.

Comment: @Ryan Updated. Please have a look

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: That's still not right. Why are you keying off the first item (`item[0]`)? Also, I've answered this question in a different post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60269057/11809808.

Comment: @Ryan Brooke Payne  No I'm not key first element, I'm taking the first character in the item.

Comment: If you update your example to match my other post, I will upvote your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208056/discussion-between-ryan-brooke-payne-and-prasana-kannan).

Comment: Thanks @RyanBrookePayne for correcting for me. Initially I thought it very similar to js, but I've identified few difference after reading doc. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2):

The `typeof` operator in JavaScript returns `object` for an array value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

When you call toString(), you are simply printing out the values of the array that you have.

Also, Prasana Kannan is correct. This is not a good use of reduce. Reduce is used to return one value from a set of values (https://engineering.khanacademy.org/posts/lets-reduce.htm). Using filter would be more elegant here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

As for why reduce is not recognized as a function, you may have to look up your version of Nashorn to see if it even includes an implementation for reduce.

Comment: Filter throws the same error: `jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: list.filter is not a function`. Is there another way to filter the list?

Comment: I've solved the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60269352/11809808. Thanks for the filter suggestion.