# Why does Array.prototype.filter() throw an error in Magnolia JavaScript models?

Tags: javascript, freemarker, ecmascript-5, nashorn, magnolia

I'm attempting to filter a FreeMarker list in a [Magnolia JavaScript model](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/How+to+work+with+JavaScript+models) using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

**List**

```
[#assign list = [1, 2, 3]]
```

**Model**

```js
var Model = function() {
  this.filterList = function(list) {
    return list.filter(function(item) {
      return item === 2
    });
  }
};

new Model();
```

**Usage**

```
${model.filterList(list)}
```

However, I get the following error.

```sh
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: TypeError: list.filter is not a function
```

Nashorn was implemented using [ECMAScript-262 5.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20).

> The Nashorn JavaScript engine was first incorporated into JDK 8 via JEP 174 as a replacement for the Rhino scripting engine. When it was released, it was a complete implementation of the ECMAScript-262 5.1 standard. — [JEP 335: Deprecate the Nashorn JavaScript Engine](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335)

Why despite the fact that Nashorn follows ECMAScript-262 5.1 do I get an error when using `Array.prototype.filter()`?

Comment: Whatever `list` is, it's not something that offers a `map`, `filter` or `reduce` method

Comment: FreeMarker may be creating an `ArrayList`.

Comment: because list might not be an array.

Comment: @Pointy When I dump (`${cmsfn.dump(list, 3, true)}`) the value of `list`, I get a Java `Sequence`. Now it makes sense why I can't use map, filter, and reduce.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for your help. I answered my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60269352/11809808.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FreeMarker list you are passing to the model is a [sequence](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_direct_seuqence), not a JavaScript array.

```
Sequence (3)
  0 = 1 (BigDecimal)
  1 = 2 (BigDecimal)
  2 = 3 (BigDecimal)
```

To solve the issue, convert the FreeMarker list you are passing to the model to a JavaScript array using [`Java.from()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html#A1147227). For example:

```js
var Model = function() {
  this.filterList = function(list) {
    return Java.from(list).filter(function(item) {
      return item === 2
    });
  }
};

new Model();
```